# Universal links, continueUserActivity and sourceApplication not being called

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-universal-links

I finally manage to do universal links, if I tap the link it will open my app. but it doesn't show up in continue user activity or source application. Because I want to redirect it to the specific view controller. For example if I open `"https://www.myWeb.com/forgotPassword"`, it will redirect to `forgotPasswordViewController`, and I need to read the link.

Why doesn't it show up in continue user activity?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    print(url)
    let urlHost : String = url.host as String!
    print("HELLO")
    
        let main : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let inner : ResetPasswordViewController = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResetPasswordViewController") as! ResetPasswordViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = inner
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true;
    
   
    
}

func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
        print(url)
        print("HELLO WORLD")
    }
    return true
}
```

And this is what happened with the source application; can someone tell me why it becomes like that?

[image: sourceApplication]

Comment: "https:// www.myWeb.com/forgotPassword" - there is a space between "https://" and "www"

Comment: the space i added just to be able showed in this post, actualy i don't space in the link

Comment: Please include the code formatted as code and not as a screenshot.

Comment: @DavidPasztor edited

Comment: Do you have 'application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)' implemented? If yes, that will be the function called with 'launchOptions' containing the keys with 'userActivity' and the 'URL' that was used to open the app.

Comment: i don't understand  this sentence "that will be the function called with 'launchOptions' containing the keys with 'userActivity' and the 'URL' that was used to open the app." can you explain more detail ?

Comment: @davidPasztor solved it's really silly, it's just because i put AnyObject instead of Any. but the compiler doesn't tell any error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SOLVED 
it's just because of type Data, i put AnyObject instead of Any.
but the compiler doesn't tell me if AnyObject can't be used

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    print("Continue User Activity: ")
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
        print(url.absoluteString)
        //handle url
    }
    return true
}
```